# Does any fractional ideal of $R$ always contain a non-zero element of $R$?

Tags: modules, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain. Let $A$ be a non-zero fractional ideal of $R.$ Then can we say that $A$ always contains a non-zero element of $R$?

Please help me in this regard. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fractional ideals are nonzero by definition, 
so $A$ contains an element $r/s$ with $r$, $s$
nonzero elements of $R$. Then $r=(r/s)s\in A$.

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks @Lord Shark The Unknown for your kind help.